# Connecting full text research papers to a graph GDS (Neo4j)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-data-science

I'm looking for tips or tricks on how to connect full text research papers to a graph in Neo4j.

I've researched some APIs that allow you to connect to scholarly articles - are there any best practices for doing this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could use opencitations bulk data for the structure / topology.

And then run NLP algorithms on the texts to extract entity nodes for topics, keywords, people, organizations, compounds etc.

see here for some examples from Tomaz Bratanic

https://towardsdatascience.com/construct-a-biomedical-knowledge-graph-with-nlp-1f25eddc54a0

https://towardsdatascience.com/from-text-to-knowledge-the-information-extraction-pipeline-b65e7e30273e

https://towardsdatascience.com/extract-knowledge-from-text-end-to-end-information-extraction-pipeline-with-spacy-and-neo4j-502b2b1e0754